# A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, network

We have an application in Azure which connects to SQL Server on-premise over hybrid connection
Every 4-5 requests from 1000 would fail with error 10054:

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server.
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

What we've tried:

- restarted app in Azure
- increased ConnectTimeOut and CommandTimeOut in application
- rebooted Windows hosting SQL Server
- installed OS and SQL Server patches on-prem
- checked SQL Server error log, no related errors
- sysadmin checked firewall/switches - ZERO packet loss or drops
- performed update of firmware and drivers (network, sas, raid)

Also checked this:

- remote access in SQL Server is turned on, obviously
- SQL Server Browser turned off, but there is only one default instance
- hybrid connection manager is up to date
- SqlClient version is up to date (System.Data.SqlClient: 4.0.0.0)
- databases auto_close = OFF
- sessions are not getting killed by anyone
- server does not go to sleep or energy saving mode
- TCP chimney is disabled
- SPN config is OK with Kerberos Configuration Manager

**None of above helped. Resolution:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187005(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Although link is for Windows Server 2003, it worked for Windows Server 2016
Solution was to add registry entry SynAttackProtect - DWORD - 00000000

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\

As we understand, requests from Azure were too rapid sometimes so system thought it was under attack ? We added registry entry and stopped getting error 10054. Team is happy and already moved on to other tasks

I thought posting above information on DBA SE may help other guys troubleshooting this issue

**Question:**

Is this solution optimal, as it seem to open server to SYN-flood and denial-of-service attacks ?
Are there any alternatives in fixing 10054 error ?

Comment: Which client driver are you using?

Comment: @Charlieface this is what I've got from developers:  App is using Dapper Micro ORM over native SQL libraries to connect to the database:
Dapper versions: 1.42.0 & 1.50.5
System.Data.SqlClient: 4.0.0.0

Comment: How many clients do you have making requests concurrently? Connection pooling should normally keep the number of physical connections down to 1 or 2 per client. I suspect connection pooling is not working properly, probably because the application is not disposing/closing the `SqlConnection` object correctly. So every time the client makes a new request then a new physical connection is opened, requiring a TCP SYN/ACK handshake, as well as TLS and TDS handshakes, all of which could cause you problems if done too many times.